# WebM With a Still Image and an Audio

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, flac, wav, webm

How can I join together a cover and a music into WebM with **the best audio quality** using `ffmpeg`? I really can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Stream copy

The preferred option is to [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the audio with `-c:a copy`. This is analogous to copying and pasting it into the WebM. The downside is that it has to already be in a format suitable for WebM such as Vorbis or Opus.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -i audio.opus -map 0 -map 1:a -c:v libvpx-vp9 -vf format=yuv420p -c:a copy -shortest output.webm
```

## Opus

If you have some other audio format then `ffmpeg` can encode it to Opus which is a modern format supported by WebM:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -i audio.mp3 -map 0 -map 1:a -c:v libvpx-vp9 -vf format=yuv420p -c:a libopus -shortest output.webm
```

- This assumes your `ffmpeg` was configured with `--enable-libopus`.
- You can see additional encoding options with `ffmpeg -h encoder=libopus`.
- The defaults for libopus are good so you don't have to add additional options.

#### More info

- [FFmpeg Wiki: VP9](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9)